# Django 1.11 - convert a datetime string with timezone 2018-01-01T00:00:00+03:00 into datetime object to be used for queryset

Tags: python, django, postgresql, datetime, django-1.11

I am using Django 1.11 and Postgres 9.4.

How can I convert this

```
2018-01-01T00:00:00+03:00
```

into a datetime object that can be used for queryset like below

```
Tracking.objects.filter(created_at__gte=input_datetime)
```

for Z time I can use this:

```
input_datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime("2019-11-01T01:36:56.233032Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
```

but how can I make it work for this time (which seems to have timezone).
I tried this but it didnt work.

```
input_datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-01-01T00:00:00+03:00','%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')
```

Here is my model.py

```
class Tracking(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Comment: Try removing the `.` in your format string: `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%f%z'`

Comment: does not work--> ValueError: time data '2018-01-01T00:00:00+03:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%f%z' .... i did this: input_datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-01-01T00:00:00+03:00','%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%f%z')

Comment: In that case you are using a Python version < 3.7 and also need to remove the last `:` in your `date_string` argument.

Comment: im using Python 3.6.3

Answer (score 2):

You can actually use Pythons standard `datetime` lib for this. Somethid like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
a = '2018-01-01T00:00:10+03:00'
datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 0, 0, 10, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=10800)))
```

It will give you a `datetime.datetime` object which you can use for watever later on.

Comment: i have interest in this, where do I put "a" ?

Answer (score 1):

With the standard`datetime` module this should work:

```
datetime.strptime('2018-01-01T00:00:00+03:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
```

With the Django's timezone module, the closest match format that I got is this:

```
timezone.datetime.strptime('2018-01-01T00:00:00+0300', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
```

This example doesn't include `:` in the offset part 2018-01-01T00:00:00+**0300**.

Comment: it works, im trying to understand abit, you mean timezone +0300 is not accounted for ?

Comment: what is %z for ? isnt that for +0300 ?

Comment: Docs are missing some examples, Henry's answer proves that %z will catch also +03:00

Comment: didnt work datetime.strptime('2018-01-01T00:00:00+03:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'). AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'

Comment: this also didnt work - datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-01-01T00:00:00+03:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z') . ValueError: time data '2018-01-01T00:00:00+03:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'